# How to retrive cellular network information from XCode, iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there any APIs available in which can provide me with the following details:

1. Signal Quality
2. Country Code
3. Network Code
4. Area Code
5. Cell ID
6. Base Station ID
7. GPRS Cell ID
8. GPRS Base Station ID
9. Signal Strength;
10. Max Signal Strength

But what I need if it is not available to retrive Signal Strength in dbm

Note: I can get this information manually by dialing *3001#12345#* as shown in the following screen shot from my iPhone (Signal Strength showed in the upper left corner in dbm):

https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/Qf6MBY2jtfpWImTyTHk4Gg?feat=directlink

Comment: Are you intending to distribute your app via Apple iTunes? If so, then you will be disappointed to hear that there is no such thing as a public API allowing you to retrieve that information.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has not officially provided any API to calculate the signal strength.
But you can refer to official `Core Telephony` framework ([CTCarrier Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009596)) to get some of the details such as Country Code,Network Code etc.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer, Very important data to me from above list is getting signal strength in dbm if there is any way can I get this information it is not clasified data to use in my application in Android you can get this number in just a line of code..

Comment: @zaaterah,you are right in android it is possible but as far as i am aware, in iOS there is no official way to determine the signal strength.